# Request rate limiting/throttling in a multi tenant cloud application

Tags: cloud, multi-tenant, rate-limiting

I have a multi tenant cloud based web application running on several nodes.

Application is behind a load balancer but needs sticky sessions.

Now i want to implement request limiting/throttling in my application.

I don't want to implement distributed rate limiting mechanisms which would require me to have a separate component like Redis, Memcache. Because that itself could become a bottleneck and might need to have high availability for that. And i don't want to maintain another component.

Would like to know will it be useful to implement tenant scoped request throttling on a particular node with memory based data structure.

Load balancer would take care of the load but yes one user can still fire lot of requests due to sticky sessions.

Best Regards,

Saurav

Comment: Since you don't want to maintain another component, it seems that you'll have to implement your own rate limiting logic, inside your application. Is that a possibility?

Comment: Yes this is what we would do